# Is there a way to know the time remaining for the alarm to go off or the elapsed time since alarm started from API

Tags: android

Assume I set alarm to off after 8 hours from now using AlarmManager. I exit the App and open it back. **Now I want to know the time remaining for the alarm to go off or the elapsed time since alarm started. Is there a way to know this from Android API**. Of course one way is by the calculation of (currentTime - Alarm started time). But if the user changes his device time then it's a problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to know this from Android API.

No, sorry.

> Of course one way is by the calculation of (currentTime - Alarm started time). But if the user changes his device time then it's a problem.

The alarm will behave the same as your proposed logic, AFAIK. If you use an `RTC` or `RTC_WAKEUP` alarm, it will go off at your stated time, regardless of whether or not the time on the device changed. Conversely, if you use `ELAPSED_REALTIME` or `ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP`, then whether the time on the device changed is irrelevant.